# Facebook Open Graph OG tags not being fetched dynamically in News Section

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have set my meta og tags dynamically. When it's the home page, the image will be set do the default logo, and the description will be the default description, too.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="website-logo.png" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
```

But when at the news section it gets the news title and image as both og:description and og:image.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="cover-of-the-news.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Title of The News" />
```

The problem is whenever I share any **news pages**, or I try to URL lint the any news url, Facebook only gets the standard image and description, not the intended **news** image and **news** description.

*If you were to inspect the meta elements in the document, you'd see that they are being dynamically set properly. News pages get the right og:image and og:description, they just don't get the right title and image **at Facebook**.*

Comment: What is the url that is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try using FACEBOOK debugger to know about the og meta tags that are loaded dynamically. And the reason for not showing right image and title.